# Reading Parquet Via Spark from HDFS location

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on a requirement using Spark .

My Cluster has a HDFS directory named /user/cloudera/omega/mdp/  partitioned by transdate. All the files inside the partitioned directory are parquet files .

Also I have hive table named "mdp" pointing those parquet files.

Basically my requirement is to read these parquet files and do some Processing using some logic and store the processed data in another HDFS location.

I am trying to read those parquet files via spark-sql using sqlContext and I am able to read them as well by using below code

I would like to know what is safest way to read those parquet files

**Option 1 :** Read the  parquet files by passing the HDFS path as below

```
scala>  val df = sqlContext.read.parquet ("/user/cloudera/omega/mdp/transdate=*")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [trans_id: bigint, trans_grp_id:  string, trans_amount_id: bigint, transdate: int]
```

**Option 2 :** Read them by passing the hive select query

```
scala> val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from omega.mdp")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [trans_id: bigint, trans_grp_id: string, trans_amount_id: bigint, transdate: int]
```

From the above two options which one is the safest way to read  the data?

Also can we read these  parquet files via sparkContext alone ?

Comment: [HiveContex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) provides more robust SQL parser than **sqlContext**. If you need additional features include the ability to write queries using the more complete HiveQL use HiveContex otherwise use **sqlContext**.